# Beautifulsoup html parser attribute crawling question

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.11st.co.kr/products/4976666261?NaPm=ct=ld6p5dso|ci=e5e093b328f0ae7bb7c9b67d5fd75928ea152434|tr=slsbrc|sn=17703|hk=87f5ed3e082f9a3cd79cdd0650afa9612c37d9e8&utm_term=&utm_campaign=%B3%D7%C0%CC%B9%F6pc_%B0%A1%B0%DD%BA%F1%B1%B3%B1%E2%BA%BB&utm_source=%B3%D7%C0%CC%B9%F6_PC_PCS&utm_medium=%B0%A1%B0%DD%BA%F1%B1%B3'

html = '''
<div class="side_sm"><a href="javascript:;" class="gift c_product_btn c_product_btn_gift" data-log-actionid-label="gift" data-log-body="{current_product_no:4976666261,product_price:1310000,buynow_draw_info:{product_object:[{product_no:4976666261,current_product_no:4976666261,first_view_product_no:0,master_product_no:null,similar_product_code:null,group_product_no:null,group_product_firstview_no:null,group_product_category_no:null,group_product_count:null,group_product_info:null,product_name:a((옵토마[OPTOMA] EOP-H500 프로젝터 (5000안시 FULL-HD 55000:1),product_image_url:https://cdn.011st.com/11dims/resize/600x600/quality/75/11src/pd/v2/6/6/6/2/6/1/BCkvx/4976666261_B.jpg,product_price:1310000,last_discount_price:1159920,seller_name:주노글로리,large_category_name:영상가전,middle_category_name:프로젝터,small_category_name:사무/회의용,detail_category_name:,large_category_no:1001435,middle_category_no:1002792,small_category_no:1006697,detail_category_no:,colloseo_brand_add_display_category_no:,colloseo_brand_code:22236,catalog_no:43823399,is_now_delivery:false,is_adult_product:false,is_sale:true,trace_meta_category:,smartoption:N,display_category_no:,add_product_yn:N,is_img_search:false,shockingdeal_yn:N,prd_type_vars:{tour11_yn:N,smart_option_yn:N,brand_yn:Y,shockingdeal_yn:N,movie_yn:N,talk11_yn:Y},detailCategoryNoToLong:0}]},group_product_no:0,send_impression:Y}" data-is-send-log="true">선물</a></div>
'''

json_data=soup.find('div',class_='side_sm').find('a').attrs('data-log-body')
print(json_data)
```

TypeError
'dict' object is not callable

I want to get the value of the dictionary, which is the value of the data-log-body attribute of the tag a under the 'class' side_sm of the 'div' tag.

I keep getting error handling, so please give me some advice on how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a `dict` with key use square brackets:

```
.attrs['data-log-body']
```

> Use tag.get('attr') if you’re not sure attr is defined, just as you
> would with a Python dictionary.
> [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#miscellaneous)

So I would recommend to use:

```
.get('data-log-body')
```